# Cloud Function executed successfully but notification not showing android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

In an android app, I am using FCM for sending notifications, the cloud function executed successfully, as shown in the firebase console log, but in my device its not showing any notification, what could be the reason ?

Below is the code for my index.js

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');
let admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/messages/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {
     console.log('notifying start1');
    const message = event.data.current.val();
    const senderUid = message.from;
    const receiverUid = message.to;
    console.log('SenderId '+senderUid + ' Receiver Id '+receiverUid);
    const promises = [];
 console.log('notifying start2');
    if (senderUid == receiverUid) {
        //if sender is receiver, don't send notification
        promises.push(event.data.current.ref.remove());
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }
      console.log('notifying start3');
    const getInstanceIdPromise = admin.database().ref(`/users/${receiverUid}/accessToken`).once('value');
      console.log('notifying start4');
    const getReceiverUidPromise = admin.auth().getUser(receiverUid);
console.log('notifying start5');
    return Promise.all([getInstanceIdPromise, getReceiverUidPromise]).then(results => {
        const accessToken = results[0].val();
        const receiver = results[1];
        console.log('notifying ' + receiverUid + ' about ' + message.body + ' from ' + senderUid);
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'Firebase Notification',
                body: message.body,
            }
        };
        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(accessToken, payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            });   
            });
            });
```

Kindly help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you send message from the fire-base console.

Comment: yes from firebase console its working.

Comment: What message do you get in the Cloud Functions log in the dashboard?

Comment: this is the response i am getiing  results: [ { error: [Object] } ],
  canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
  failureCount: 1,
  successCount: 0,
  multicastId: 5973854734577752000 }   Function execution took 1497 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

Comment: Are tou positive that you are sending to the corresponding token? Could you also post your code for `onMessageReceived()`

Comment: public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
     
     // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
      
        }
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        notifyUser(remoteMessage.getFrom(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

Comment: @sara do you solve this problem?

Comment: @sara Do you get any solution

Answer (score 23):

Had the same problem and couldn't understand what was wrong since the error details were not shown i.e. { error: [Object] }

```
Successfully sent message: { results: [ { error: [Object] } ], 
                             canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0, 
                             failureCount: 1, 
                             successCount: 0, 
                             multicastId: 5487635521698134000 
                           }
```

So changed/added a log in the cloud function code to access the error details i.e. `console.log(response.results[0].error);`.

code (in the cloud function):

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                console.log(response.results[0].error);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            });
```

error details:

```
{ Error: The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons. See the error documentation for more details. Remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages.
at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)
at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:25:28)
at new FirebaseMessagingError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:130:23)
at Function.FirebaseMessagingError.fromServerError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:154:16)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:80:63
at Array.forEach (native)
at mapRawResponseToDevicesResponse (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:76:26)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:223:24
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered',
     message: 'The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons. See the error documentation for more details. Remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages.' } }
```

Not sure if you have the same error I do...